# How to install Linux on my very old laptop Dell Inspirion Mini 10

Tags: system-installation, laptop

I want to install Linux on my very old laptop Dell Inspirion Mini 10, which looks like this one https://www.olx.pl/d/oferta/komputer-laptop-netbook-dell-inspirion-mini-10-CID99-IDIET29.html#26e1f57d20

On this page it says

- Processor Intel® Atom™ CPU N270 1.60 GHz
- RAM memory 1GB
- Hard drive 500GB

When I tried to install https://q4os.org/ on this machine I got the following message:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
> Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you attempted to install the distribution for 64-bit x86 processors, but the N270 is 32-bit only.

Download and install the version for 32-bit x86 systems (called "32bit / i386").

Comment: Yes. "Q4OS Centaurus, Trinity, install-cd - 32bit / i386" worked fine. Thank you!

Comment: @Artem: Questions deserve answers.  Answers should be posted as answers, not comments, so they can be voted up (if helpful) or down (if not).  Nothing to do with points.